# Typescript reference value of indexed object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function that receives an object argument defined like this:

```js
interface MyObject {
  [key: string]: (SomeTypeA | SomeTypeB)[]
}
```

The signature of the object is dynamically generated from a JSON Schema and may contain more properties in the future yet it serves as the single source of truth for `MyObject` values. Is there a way for me to reference the `(SomeTypeA | SomeTypeB)[]` part of the interface when I have a reference to `MyObject`?

E.g.: like this:

```js
const doSomething = (withObject: valueof MyObject) => {
 // withObject is either SomeTypeA or SomeTypeB or whatever the value of properties is inside MyObject
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the underneath types like this :

```
type SomeTypeA = string;
type SomeTypeB = number;

interface MyObject {
  [key: string]: (SomeTypeA | SomeTypeB)[],
}

type ExtractType<T> = T[keyof T];

const c: ExtractType<MyObject> = [50, 'foo'];
```